# How can I make the fan in my computer turn off when it's suspended?

Tags: kernel, hibernate, suspend, fan, bios

When my computer is suspended, the GPU, CPU and power supply fans all continue to run.

I don't think I've ever been able to get them to turn off, short of hibernating or turning the computer off. I have some theories as to where to begin, but what I'd like are some more solid ideas.

<strike>I built this computer myself, so I think it's possible that I didn't connect the fans to a proper power supply, so one theory is that I need to open the computer, and move the fan's wire somewhere else on the motherboard. If this is correct, is there a way to know where to move it?</strike> <-- This theory doesn't make sense now that I realize it's three different fans that keep running.

My other theory is that I need to do something in my BIOS to make this change, and my third theory is that this is an Ubuntu thing that I need to fix on the software side.

Does anybody know how to figure out why the fans never turn off, or what to do to fix them? They DO turn off when the computer is hibernating, but I don't like doing that because it takes a very long time to boot up from hibernation.

Comment: Which fan are you talking about? The CPU fan, another fan? How is it connected on the motherboard? is it a socket which can be regulated, or is it directly connected to the power supply?

Comment: I don't think it's an Ubuntu thing. I've never had or heard of that problem.

Comment: Seems more off-topic than on-topic to me?

Comment: The difference between hibernation and suspending is tremendous. Hibernation is basically switching the computer off. The difference is only the fact that the system status is saved and loaded after starting it up. Suspend means to keep all the RAM under power, hence the power supply is still on, while the peripherals and cpus are switched off.

Comment: Updated to address @txwikinger's question.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: @jrg, Nope. Had to replace the computer so I could have a silent one in my bedroom at night (it was due anyway).

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, and solved it by going to BIOS into "Power Management Setup" set "ACPI Suspend Type" to "S3 (STR)".

STR stands for "Suspend to RAM", [screenshot and more in here](http://gsmblog.com/post/Difference-between-S1-%28POS%29-and-S3-%28STR%29-standby-mode-in-BIOS.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

This may depend on how old your computer is. I believe that this must be a supported mode in newer BIOSes (I believe that you may want to search for "S3 Standby" somewhere in your BIOS options).

Comment: Hrmm...nothing in the bios about standby. There are some power settings in there, which I adjusted, but doing so just removed my suspend button altogether.

I did discover though that suspend doesn't work consistently...so that's interesting.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the exact same problem with my computer. I would suspend, but the power supply, case and cpu fans would continue running. It turns out that I needed to change a setting in the BIOS to properly enable the suspend to RAM. In my BIOS the setting was located in the ACPI settings page. On that page there was a setting, "Suspend to RAM", that needed to be set to "Auto" instead of "Disabled". I have seen other BOISes that abbreviate this setting to STR. After I made the change and rebooted, suspend was working correctly, i.e. all fans and the power supply now turn off when the computer is suspended.

Answer (score 0):

After multiple researches and several attempts of trial and error, I found that Vista x-64 will not turn off the fans in standby mode unless all "advanced power settings" are either set to "Disabled" when available, or set to "Maximum Power Saving" when available.  Once you establish a profile that has these characteristics, then the standby mode will shut down the fans.  That's true whether you use the Power Button, or the command "rundll32.exe powrprof.dll, SetSuspenState".  Make sure you turn Hibernate state off by either using the disk cleaning utility or by setting it to off using the line command "powercfg -h off".

Good luck and hope this helps.

Comment: Vista is not a linux system